# Five graded difficulty isosceles right triangle into square tilings

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, dissection, tiling, triangle

Similar to:
[Unlucky tiling: Arrange thirteen right isosceles triangles into a square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64528/unlucky-tiling-arrange-thirteen-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square)

[Two difficult "Seventeen right isosceles triangles into a square" tilings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/two-difficult-seventeen-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square-tilings)

[V.hard problem, 20 right isosceles triangles into a square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64637/v-hard-problem-20-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square)

Each tiling has only one solution, the smaller lists will be easier but all should be possible by hand, computers allowed.

The five challenges are to arrange $7, 13, 14, 15, 16$ right isosceles triangles of the listed areas into a square of area $882$ with no gaps or overlaps. The square has a diagonal of length $42$.

$7:$ $9, 18, 36, 72, 144, 162, 441$

$13:$ $16, 18, 25, 32, 36, 50, 64, 72, 81, 98, 100, 128, 162$

$14:$ $1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 16, 18, 25, 32, 36, 64, 98, 128, 441$

$15:$ $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 25, 32, 36, 50, 64, 72, 98, 121, 128, 225$

$16:$ $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 18, 25, 32, 49, 50, 64, 81, 98, 128, 144, 162$

The answer tick will be given to whomever posts the greatest number of "placed triangles" in completed puzzles first. In the unlikely event of a tie, the solver that got the highest scoring single puzzle wins.

By way of illustration/clarification, here are the right isosceles triangles of area

$1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 18, 50$

arranged into a $10\times 10$ square:

[image: 10x10_7]

Comment: I like these riddles :D

Comment: I like these tiling problems too. I'm trying to think of an approach to these that's better than just tapping them into [PolySolver](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/polysolver.htm) and hoping to be lucky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the solutions to the five problems.

> [image]
>  I was able to find by hand the first three solutions. The first one, in particular, can be downsized by a factor of 3 in all dimensions to simplify work. The last two I used PolySolver to help. The general methodology is to stack several triangles, often doubling in area, together.

Comment: Yup all the same as mine, up to R&R. I'll post my pix for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, to see all solutions in my 'style':

> [image: 7]
>  [image: 13]
>  [image: 14]
>  [image: 15]
>  [image: 16]