# Two difficult "Seventeen right isosceles triangles into a square" tilings

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, dissection, tiling, triangle

Similar to:
[Unlucky tiling: Arrange thirteen right isosceles triangles into a square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64528/unlucky-tiling-arrange-thirteen-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square)

[Five graded difficulty isosceles right triangle into square tilings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64586/five-graded-difficulty-isosceles-right-triangle-into-square-tilings)

[V.hard problem, 20 right isosceles triangles into a square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64637/v-hard-problem-20-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square)

Each tiling has only one solution, these might be possible by hand, computers allowed.

The two challenges are to arrange $17$ right isosceles triangles of the listed areas into a square of area $968$ with no gaps or overlaps. The square has a diagonal of length $44$.

$1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 16, 18, 25, 32, 36, 49, 50, 64, 81, 162, 169, 242$
$1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 32, 36, 49, 50, 64, 98, 100, 121, 128, 225$

The answer tick will be given to whomever posts the solution to the second puzzle first, or the first if nobody gets the second. Only because the second looks slightly harder to me.

By way of illustration/clarification, here are the right isosceles triangles of area

$1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 18, 50$

arranged into a $10\times 10$ square:

[image: 10x10_7]

Comment: #pouts# the last one wasn't even solved yet! I'm still working on it lol

Comment: No rush. I'll give you another half hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the solutions to both questions:

> [image]

Comment: Yup that's em. I'll put up mine in my style too.

Answer (score 0):

In my pic style for completeness:

> [image: 44_17_17]