# 20 right isosceles triangles into a square

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, dissection, tiling, triangle

Similar:
[Unlucky tiling: Arrange thirteen right isosceles triangles into a square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64528/unlucky-tiling-arrange-thirteen-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square)

[Five graded difficulty isosceles right triangle into square tilings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64586/five-graded-difficulty-isosceles-right-triangle-into-square-tilings)

[Two difficult "Seventeen right isosceles triangles into a square" tilings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/two-difficult-seventeen-right-isosceles-triangles-into-a-square-tilings?noredirect=1#comment195914_64613)

The challenge is to fit the smallest $20$ integer-sided scaled right isosceles triangles into a square with diagonal $46$

For convenience, I list the areas of the triangles:

$1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 16, 18, 25, 32, 36, 49, 50, 64, 72, 81, 98, 100, 121, 128, 144$

There are four ways of doing it (not two as originally posted). A brave person it would be who tackled this by hand.

By way of illustration/clarification, here are the right isosceles triangles of area

$1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 18, 50$

arranged into a $10\times 10$ square:

[image: 10x10_7]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are at least two solutions (up to reflection and rotation)

> [image]
>  The trapezoid outlined in red can be flipped.
>  [image]
>  This is presumably the other "substantially different" solution (not counting the above trapezoid flip as different).

Comment: Your second solution is the same as one of mine. Your first is not... which means my software butchered something. I'm re-running it finding all 32 solutions, ie I turned off the code that rejects R&R solutions. Originally it found 4 solutions, ie rejected 7 out of every 8. But two of them were reflections. There should be four solutions, I'll have to ID them by hand. Meanwhile I'm awarding your answer...

Comment: OK my R&R code needs fixing for triangle solving... there are 4 solutions, my two and your three (with an overlap of 1). I'll post the full set in my graphic style for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the four solutions. In the first diagram, there is a flippable area bottom centre so two solutions from that, as noted by @Phenomist:

> [image: 46_3_4]
>  [image: 46_1_2]